# Webpack doesn't append the preceding slash

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have followed up my error and realised this statement is behind all of it

```
script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + chunkId + ".app.js";
```

my src is

```
const langFile = await import(`lang/${i18n.locale}`);
```

Am trying to lazy load a language file, and the source now becomes

```
http://localhost:8000/user/0.app.js
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8000/0.app.js
```

Any suggestion on how i can resolve this, thanks.

Comment: Do you have `publicPath` set in your webpack config?

Comment: nope, so that was the problem, thanks, it works now

Comment: @helb I have changed content of language files, why doesn't it change?